# Can't logout Symfony 5 with several providers and firewall

Tags: symfony

I have to handle 2 types of authent (for an administrator part and a customer part)
I do succeed to make 2 separates authenticator with 2 separates providers and 2 separates authentication page, the 2 form connection work correctly.
But I'm facing off an issue about the logout action.

Here is the `security.yaml` sample :

```yaml
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        customer:
            pattern: ^/profile|/login
            entry_point: App\Security\CustomerAuthenticator
            provider: app_customer_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\CustomerAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: true
        administrator:
            pattern: ^/admin|/accessadmin
            entry_point: App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
            lazy: true
            provider: app_admin_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: true
```

and here is the logout function in the SecurityController.php

```
/**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
```

When I'm trying to go to the /logout URL, i actually have the exception thrown (well, you will say it is coded that way). The thing is, that if a rename one of the firewalls by the 'main' attribute, in that case, the logout function works perfectly.

I do not know what I am missing at this point... if the logout function is called anyway, is there a solution to force the log out with any function I will put in the public function `logout()`?

Comment: I'm missing a firewall rule which matches the rest of the website, which should be the last firewall rule BTW because the firewall rules are matched in order by their pattern. Usually the `main` firewall you are referring to. This is because `/logout` is not matched by any firewall. and thus the exception is shown. 
If you create a `/profile/logout` url and/or `/admin/logout` url, it should work too. Because that url is matched by a firewall rule.

Comment: Well.... thank YOU !
It's working perfectly with your solution :)